# most occurrence of a two column combination

Tags: python, pandas, combinations, multiple-columns

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ2MO.png)I have two columns 'Start Station' and 'End Station'

```
| Start Station | End Station |
|:--------------|:------------|
| A             | C           |
| A             | C           |
| B             | D           |
| C             | A           |
| A             | D           |
| C             | A           |
| C             | B           |
```

as you can see the most common combination is A & C
I'm trying to write a code in python using pandas so that the output is **"The most common combination is between A and C"**
I found a lot of helpful codes for this but unfortunately couldn't find a code with the output that I need.
I hope I clarified my question enough and thanks in advance

I added an image because I'm new to stackoverflow and couldn't import the table example

Comment: Does order of the star/end matter? Do you want all maxes? Do you have more columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`idxmax` will return a tuple with the most frequent combination:

```
df.groupby(['Start Station', 'End Station']).value_counts().idxmax()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be interpreted in many different ways (do you want all max? Does order of the route matter (A->C ≠ C->A?), etc.

You can use the first index of `value_counts`' output as it is sorted by default.

```
df.value_counts().index[0]
```

Output: `('A', 'C')`

If you want all the max in case of tie:

```
df.value_counts().loc[lambda x: x==x.max()].index.tolist()
```

Output: `[('A', 'C'), ('C', 'A')]`

If the order doesn't matter:

```
df[['Start Station', 'End Station']].agg(set, axis=1).value_counts().index[0]
```

Output: `{'A', 'C'}`

If you have other columns:

```
df[['Start Station', 'End Station']].value_counts().index[0]
```

Comment: I’m sorry the question isn’t clear enough, first the order doesn’t matter, meaning A—>C is similar to C—>A as long as it’s between the same two destinations, also there are other columns but I want the combination between start & end stations, and I want the most occurrences between start and end

Comment: Then `df[['Start Station', 'End Station']].agg(set, axis=1).value_counts().index[0]` works